# Current table name retrieval in dbt project file

Tags: sql, jinja2, amazon-redshift, dbt

I'm trying to get the model names in the post-hook action to be able to store the latest model run times as into the audit table. I'm adding the post hook query in the `dbt_project.yml` file since I need the hook to be triggered for all the models.

```
models:
  +bind: false
  data_warehouse:
        data_mart:
          +post_hook:
            - "INSERT INTO {{ target.schema }}__audit._model_run (model_name, run_time) SELECT '{{ this }}', GETDATE()"
          schema: 'data_mart'
          materialized: view
```

The problem is that `{{ this }}` does not work, when I build the models it returns nothing for `{{ this }}` block:

```
INSERT INTO dev__audit._model_run (model_name, run_time) SELECT , GETDATE()
```

Tried to insert `{{ this }}` without the quotes as well, still returns nothing.
Any ideas what could be a solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT- Turns out this is simpler than originally thought. Just move your query into a macro. References to `this` will work as long as you're not putting it directly into `dbt_project.yml`.

```
models:
  +bind: false
  data_warehouse:
        data_mart:
          +post_hook:
            - "{{ log_results() }}"
          schema: 'data_mart'
          materialized: view
```

Macro:

```
{% macro log_results() %}
      INSERT INTO {{ target.schema }}__audit._model_run SELECT '{{ this }}', GETDATE();
{% endmacro %}
```

Leaving original answer to give more options

---

`this` is not available inside the `dbt_project.yml` context. You can only really reference `target`, DBT built ins, and environment variables. (Ref: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/dbt-project-yml-context)

You have two options:

###### 1) Model Post Hook

The `post-hook` within the model has access to `this`. You can simply move your insert statement to the `config` within the models themselves.

```
{{
  config({
    "materialized": 'table',
    "post-hook": "INSERT INTO {{ target.schema }}__audit._model_run (model_name, run_time) SELECT '{{ this }}', GETDATE();"
  })
}}
```

Of course, this can be tedious and repetitive.

###### 2) Use `on-run-end`

Instead of writing your result out at the end of each model, you can write out all results at the end of the job run. `on-run-end` has access to a `results` variable that you can loop through for each node in the job and get the job name, execution time, plus several other details. See: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/on-run-end-context#results

Inside `dbt_project.yml`:

```
on-run-end:
  - "{{ log_results(results, schemas) }}"
```

Then create a macro to write the results:

```
{% macro log_results(results, schemas) %}
  {% if execute %}
    {% set schema = schemas[0] %}
    {% for res in results %}
      INSERT INTO {{ schema }}__audit._model_run SELECT '{{ res.node.name }}', {{ res.execution_time }};
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Full list of what is in the `results` object: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#result-objects

And here is where you can find what is available under `results.node`: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/artifacts/manifest-json#resource-details

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Adam Kipnis! Well first option is not desired as there are plenty of models and there will be plenty more, looking for a simpler solution. Second one looks good, but if the job is running for long and I want to know the exact time when each model was executed right away, without waiting for the whole job to finish, then this solution won't work either.

Comment: indeed, using macro directly to the dbt_project.yml worked! Thanks.